# OpenGL. есть код инициализации окна, какой это OpenGL ? 3й?

Tags: opengl, glfw

```
#include <iostream>
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

void windowsResize(GLFWwindow *window,int W,int H)
{
    SCREEN_WIDTH = W;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = H;
}

int main (void) {

    GLFWwindow *window;

    if (!glfwInit() ) {

        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow ( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT , "Танчики", NULL, NULL);

    int screenWidth, screenHeigth;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeigth);

    if ( !window ) {
        glfwTerminate ();
        return - 1;

    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent ( window );
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeigth);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho (0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1000);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    void glOrtho (GLdouble left, GLdouble right, GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top,
                  GLdouble near, GLdouble far);




    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose (window))
    {
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
    glfwTerminate ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OpenGL не занимается инициализацией окон. У вас в коде сторонняя библиотека glfw.

Comment: то есть это код не OpenGL? я новичок, и не понимаю где кончается GLFW  и начинается OpenGL?

Comment: Функции из glfw начинаются с символов glfw, функции из обычного OpenGL начинаются с символов gl (не glfw, не glut и не что-либо ещё, а просто gl)

Comment: Понял,еще вопрос! я видел что в OpenGL 3+ можно рисовать с использованием шейдеров... ну прям много кода VBO, VAO... а есть где просто GLFW типа моего кода, и сразу в цикле идет рисование,  без использования шейдеров... ну glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); Вопрос, такого типа рисование не задействует GPU?

Comment: Всё задействует, конечно. Какой смысл в существовании OpenGL без GPU?

Comment: то есть массив координат вершин загружается в память GPU ? или как

Comment: Да, всё загружается в GPU

Comment: а вы не знаете как в GLFW сделать что бы размер окна не подавался изменениям? то есть что б нельзя было его уменьшить или растянуть?

Comment: @ИльяДударь можно задать размеры окна так. Задать минимум и максимум. Например вот так. glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 200, 200, 400, 400); или так glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 640, 480, GLFW_DONT_CARE, GLFW_DONT_CARE);. Вообще если у вас линукс, то установите документацию по glfw3, и она будет если это ubuntu в каталоге /usr/share/doc/libglfw3-doc/